Final Value Theorem for a function that diverges to infinity?
Is there a Final Value Theorem for a function that diverges to infinity?
That is, suppose $f(t)$ has Laplace transform $F(s)$ and $f(t)$ diverges to infinity as $t \to \infty$. Under what conditions will $sF(s)$ diverge to infinity as $s \to 0$?
Such a Final Value Theorem would complement other versions that handle the case of $f(t)$ converging to a finite value in $\mathbb{C}$. See for example [1], [2], [3].

The Laplace Final Value theorem to be valid, is assumed that $F(s)$ is a stable function.
